# Discrepancy between reported n_jobs=1 and CPU-usage in jupyter

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, gridsearchcv

I am running a GridSearchCV on a KneighborsClassifier and put the n_jobs hyperparameter on -1 , so all my CPU's are utilized for the gridsearch. So intuitively I think there should be 8 different combinations of hyperparameters being run parallel.

During the run using htop on ubuntu I can see that all 8 of my CPU's are being 99% used by python, so it looks as to be expected.
But jupyter outputs during the run

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
```

And from what I can tell from the code output, it looks like everything is being executed serial instead of parallel.

So what is exactly going on here?

EDIT: The code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
param_grid_knn=[
    {
        'weights' : ['uniform','distance'],
        'n_jobs' : [-1],
        'n_neighbors' : [3,5,7],
        'p' :[1,2]
    }
]

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(knn,param_grid_knn,cv=5,scoring='accuracy',return_train_score=True,verbose=2,refit=True)
grid_search.fit(train_data,train_labels)
```

Comment: I assume all children are given one thread each, but there are many children, so all 8 threads are used for the majority of the time.

Comment: try to post full code, maybe this msg indicates that the `n_jobs` of KNN equals 1, can't be sure w/o full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the n_jobs=1 refers to the n_jobs used by GridSearchCV, which by default is 1 since I didn't specify it in its function call.